# get customer payment ids from CIM

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

How can I get **customer payment method ids** from **`AuthorizeNetCIM_Response`** object?

There's a method in `AuthorizeNetCIM_Response` which is supposed to return **payment method ids**

```
public function getCustomerPaymentProfileIds()
{
    $ids = (array)$this->xml->customerPaymentProfileIdList;
    return $ids["numericString"];
}
```

but calling this function results in error

> Notice: Undefined index: numericString

The response object outputs as:

```
AuthorizeNet_AuthorizeNetCIMResponse Object
(
    [xml] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [messages] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [resultCode] => Ok
                    [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [code] => I00001
                            [text] => Successful.
                        )
                )
            [profile] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [merchantCustomerId] => 10
                    [email] => user@nine.com
                    [customerProfileId] => 25441529
                    [paymentProfiles] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [firstName] => 
                                            [lastName] => 
                                            [address] => 
                                            [city] => 
                                            [zip] => 
                                            [country] => 
                                            [phoneNumber] => 
                                        )
                                    [customerPaymentProfileId] => 23298664
                                    [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [cardNumber] => XXXX2224
                                                    [expirationDate] => XXXX
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [customerType] => individual
                                    [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [firstName] => Test
                                            [lastName] => Individual
                                            [company] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [address] => 
                                            [city] => 
                                            [state] => 
                                            [zip] => 
                                            [country] => 
                                            [phoneNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [faxNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [customerPaymentProfileId] => 23299421
                                    [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [cardNumber] => XXXX0027
                                                    [expirationDate] => XXXX
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
```

and I supposed to get the array of `paymentProfiles` as

> $response->xml->profile->paymentProfiles;

but it only returning the first element of `paymentProfiles` not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there can be more then one, as per your example, you need to loop through each profile to get that information:

```
$paymentProfileIds = array();
foreach ($response->xml->profile->paymentProfiles AS $profile) {
    $paymentProfileIds[] = (string) $profile->customerPaymentProfileId;
}

print_r($paymentProfileIds);
```

Comment: the output is `Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 23298664
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 23299421
        )

)
`

Comment: Try casting that value to a string: `$paymentProfileIds[] = (string) $profile->customerPaymentProfileId;`